# Okta Redirect Url Not working when hash location is enabled in Angular

Tags: angular, okta

In my angular 6 App, I configured oktaConfig object as below, and this works fine without any issue

```js
//okataConfig.ts

export const oktaConfig = {
  url: 'https://dev-501039.oktapreview.com',
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  issuer: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/implicit/callback',
};

//routing.ts

{path: '',component: DefaultLayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{path: 'implicit/callback',component: CallbackComponent},
```

but when I enable hash location the redirect not working,

```js
// app.module.ts

providers: [
  {
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy,
  },
  AuthGuard, OktaAuthService
],
```

how should I configure in routing ?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Change **response_mode** to **query** in your authentication request instead of **fragment** (which adds another # in url). This will work and you'll get code and state as a query parameter like-

> http://{your.domain}/#/app/?code=xyz&state=pqr

```js
createRequest(code_challengeBuffer, response) {
  const code_challenge =
 this._ssoUtilityService.bufferToBase64UrlEncoded(code_challengeBuffer);
  const state = this._ssoUtilityService.createRandomString();
  const nonce = this._ssoUtilityService.createRandomString();
  this.appendParam('client_id', response.clientId, true);
  this.appendParam('nonce', nonce, true);
  this.appendParam('state', state, true);
  this.appendParam('code_challenge', code_challenge, true);
  this.appendParam('code_challenge_method', 'S256', true);
  this.appendParam('scope', 'openid profile email offline_access', true);
  this.appendParam('response_type', 'code', true);
  this.appendParam('response_mode', 'query', true);
  this.appendParam('redirect_uri', response.redirectUrl);
  window.location.href = this.url;
}
    
    // Added this function as IE11 does not support URL api
appendParam(key: string, value: string, addSeparator?: boolean) {
  this.url += key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
  if (addSeparator) { this.url += '&'; }
}
```